# Good practice when dealing with lists inside dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As far as I understand, it's problematic to have lists inside a dataframe column (if someone wants to briefly re-explain why, I am interested).

Considering the following simple example, how would you recommend transforming this data structure to get rid of the inside list column? Would it scale to dataframes that have dozens of thousands of rows already?

```
        a        b 
____________________
    1:   ""   [1,2,3]
    2:  "foo"   []
```

Comment: see [``explode``](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

Comment: @sushanth nice, looks v. handy. But if the dataframe is already v. large, that also means the number of rows is going to .. explode.. ? Is this the best practice?

Comment: it depends on what you are doing, but an alternative is to make the list a string with `.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))`

Comment: it's problematic if you need to work with the list as elements, if you are working the lists as a whole list then it's fine for the general case

Comment: @Jimmar you mean it's fine to keep the list in the cell? Or do you mean it's fine to use .join? .join is not an option for me.

Comment: it's fine to keep it, it depends on how you are planning to use it, another option would be to convert it to a json list (so it's similar to the join method) but then you can convert it back whenever you need to